# How to parse a json string in Kibana message?

Tags: kibana

I am sending a json message to Kibana and would like to parse the json message into fields so that i can use the fields in visualization.

here is the sample message:

```
message: {"minresponstime":100,"maxresponsetime":300}
```

I used scripted fields (painless) to read minresponsetime and maxresponsetime using substring. Is there a better way to extract the fields from json message?

I am not sure if scripted fields support json parsing.